# Strange facebook API error?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

Local and preproduction versions of my website have same configs and same source code. For some reason preproduction version unable to communicate with Facebook API. When I'm trying to login using Facebook I'm getting such strange error:

[image]

Google translates the error message like this:

"You can not load the URL: field is not a URL is included in this application areas. To download this URL, please add all domains and sub-domains for your application to the "application domains" field in the application settings."

I have tried to add my domain to the list, but it didn't help.

[image]

The truth is, I'm stuck and I would be grateful for any hint what to do with the error.

P.S. Also I have no idea why the error message is in Arabic - Server from Germany and has en_US.utf8 locale.

**Update** Settings Basic (*domain name changed*)

[image]

Comment: Can you show your Basic settings page?

Comment: @MartinBean Screenshot added to the post

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. Instead mark your answer as accepted which tells others that this has been solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue. I've used cascade of reverse proxies (nginx), which modified $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']. The modification leaded to inconsistency between generated redirect_uri and the value was specified in app settings in Facebook developer console.